# Xamarin MVVM Fill Model with a Model Property

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, properties, model

How do work with a model with a model property inside of it?

I am pulling info from an api successfully but it does not work after I try to change my model from int to model like below:

```
public class TypeModel
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int pType { get; set; }

    public DepartmentModel fDepartment { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the department model

```
public class DepartmentModel
{

    public int pDepartment { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

My ViewModel had this code and was working. Been trying to make changes as I think I need to change it in here somehow.

```
        Types.Clear();

        IEnumerable<TypesModel> types = await DataSource.GetTypesAsync(typeinfo.pType, true);

        foreach (var column in types)
        {
            Types.Add(column);
        }
```

Here is the deserialization from the api.

```
IEnumerable<TypeModel> TypeEnumerator;

public async Task<IEnumerable<TypeModel>> GetTypesAsync(bool r = false)
        {
            if (r)
            {
                var j = await HttpConstructor.GetStringAsync($"api/gettypes");
                return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<TypeModel>>(j));

            }

            return TypeEnumerator; ;
        }
```

Here is the json information being produced from the api for types

```
  {
    "pType": 10,
    "fDepartment": 1,
    "title": "Bigwig",
    "description": "For the bigwigs",
    "comments": "high priority",
    "version": "1.2.3"
  },
  {
    "pType": 11,
    "fDepartment": 1,
    "title": "Frontdesk",
    "description": "front end people",
    "comments": "none",
    "version": "1.2.4"
  }
```

Comment: What's not working?  What is the actual problem?  Are you getting an error or exception?

Comment: Got this error when I change fDepartment from int to DepartmentModel - Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 1 to type 'TestProject.Models.DepartmentModel'. Path '[0].status', line 1, position 131. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to TestProject.Models.DepartmentModel.

Comment: It sounds like your json does not match the model you're trying to deserialize into.  Fix one or the other so that they match.

Comment: thats my question. how should i do that now that i changed from an int to a model.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention deserialization or json at all, and you didn't provide sample json, and you haven't shown the code for `DepartmentModel`.  It's very difficult to provide help if we have to play 20 questions first just to figure out what you're trying to do.  It's possible that you could get Newtonsoft to handle this for you, but personally I would probably create a temp class to deserialize into and then convert that to your final class.  That's the best I can do given the limited amount of information you've provided.

Comment: ok I added DepartmentModel and what's getting deserialized above. Let me know if you need anything. Thanks

Comment: Where is the actual json?

Comment: Ok I added the json that is produced from the api to the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution going by using a Dictionary collection and avoided adjusting the model and mess up the business logic throughout the app.

I kept the original model and created a new one called TypesModel to use for list views.

```
   public class TypesModel
        {
            [PrimaryKey]
            public int pType { get; set; }

            public Dictionary<int, string> fDepartment { get; set; }

            public string Title { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }

            public string Comments { get; set; }

            public string Version { get; set; }

        }
```

Then I used Linq join to combine the information and also fill in the dictionary values.

```
    var query = from t in types
                            join d in departments
                            on t.fDeparment equals d.pDepartment
                            select new TypesModel
                            {
                                pType = t.pType,
                                fDepartment = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                                {
                                    { d.pDepartment, d.Name }
                                },  
                                Title = t.Title,
                                Description = t.Description


                            };
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I would do.  There are undoubtedly other ways to approach it

```
public class TypeModel
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int pType { get; set; }
    public int fDepartment { get; set; }
    public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

List<TypesModel> types = await DataSource.GetTypesAsync(typeinfo.pType, true); 

foreach (var type in types)
{
  type.Department = new DepartmentModel 
  { 
      pDepartment = type.fDeparment, 
      Name = "???" 
  };
}
```